# issue in import function from other file in python

Tags: python

I have two files as below:

**File1.py**

```
    import os

    import config
  class session():

    def __init__(self):
         self.appCoordinates = (0, 0, 1024, 768)


def startApp(self):
    session_launch = App("Packets and Protocols")
    if not session_launch.window():
        path1= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABC\\XYZ\\RT900"
        ver=config.version
        path2="bin\\Rt900.exe"
        path3=os.path.join(path1,ver)
        path4=os.path.join(path3,path2)
        App.open(path4);
        wait(25)
    session_launch.focus(); wait(10)
```

**File2.py**

```
    import File1
    class ospf():

         def _init_(self):
                  Add = File1.session()
          self.appCoordinates = (0, 0, 1024, 768)

         def startOspf(self):
            Add.startApp()
```

Whenever i try to import function i.e.,startApp from File1.py to File2.py. I am Getting below error message.

"NameError: global name 'Add' is not defined "

Can i know what is the issue?

Comment: you should do `self.Add = portadd.n2xSession()` and acces it like `self.Add.startApp()`

Comment: hi avasal, i tried that method too..It gave below error:   "AttributeError: ospf instance has no attribute 'Add'"

Comment: make `Add` a member of class objects by using `self` with it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `Add` a member of `ospf` class.

Something like this:

```
import File1
class ospf():
     def _init_(self):
         self.Add = portadd.n2xSession()
         self.appCoordinates = (0, 0, 1024, 768)

     def startOspf(self):
         self.Add.startApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "Add" just use "self.Add". It makes the variable Add a member of the class/object.

```
>>> class Complex:
...     def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
...         self.r = realpart
...         self.i = imagpart
...
>>> x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
>>> x.r, x.i
(3.0, -4.5)
```

Maybe this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) is useful to understand the meaning of "self" very well.